# Invoice year format YYYY to YY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not able to change second year format (REPPL/**20/2021**/00004) ==> (REPPL/**20/21**/00004)

**DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%y'),(@dt+1)**

when i add  **DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%y'),(@dt+1,'%y')** its throwing error

**PLEASE HELP THANKS**

```
INSERT INTO sales_invoice(
invoice_no,
date_invoiced,
order_num
) SELECT
CONCAT_WS('/','REPPL',DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%y'),(@dt +1),
    COALESCE(
        LPAD(
            CASE WHEN @dt > DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%Y-04-01') THEN SUM(date_invoiced > 
 DATE_FORMAT(@dt,'%Y-04-01')) ELSE SUM(date_invoiced BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%Y-04-01') - INTERVAL 
 1 YEAR AND DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%Y-04-01'))END +1,5,0),LPAD(1, 5, 0))),@dt,"132132"FROM sales_invoice;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are just passing `@dt +1` You are not formatting it at all. You need to add DATE_FORMAT for each argument in CONCAT, not just first, first will format first one only, the first `()`...

Try this, add one year interval and then format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(@dt, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%y')
```

Example:

```
CONCAT_WS('/','REPPL',DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%y'),DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(@dt, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%y')),
```

**FIDDLE:**

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**
    
---

**Query #1**

    select CONCAT_WS('/','REPPL',DATE_FORMAT('2020/08/16', '%y'),DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2020/08/16', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%y')) AS ConcatenatedString;

| ConcatenatedString |
| ------------------ |
| REPPL/20/21        |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2tfwgcjC7YJmF9YX6XwNzv/0)

Comment: @nyc3_gy I was missing one `)`  at end, just fixed it. Check the working fiddle.

Comment: please suggest me some sql training if possible. Thank you so much ..

Comment: @nyc3_gy I could not do that, I learned all I know from documentation  and SO examples and most important projects, tasks, try to solve SQL questions here. I look at at as quiz, with time, you will get how some things work. Good luck.